# so + V-ing -- correct grammatical structure?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, conjunctions, grammaticality-in-context, gerund-clauses

> "One of the incentives for capping electricity use, rather than charging different amounts according to usage, was to make access to energy equitable. Every household has the same five kW cap, irrespective of income, **so distributing** the available resources equally across the island's population."

Is "so" accompanied by a gerund a correct grammatical structure in English?

Comment: Yes. It's correct. One of the meanings of so is thus/in this way. Another example "We can do this, so ensuring that it happens."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this formation "so" is a conjunction meaning "thus" or "consequently". "So distributing" is not itself a phrase. "so + V-ing" can be a phrase where so is used as an adverb, as in "I've never been so happy". Here "so" is specifically attached to "happy". "so happy" means "as happy [as this]".